# How to find function that never called

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, function-calls, function-call

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Find never-called functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4224758/find-never-called-functions)

Hello
I know that similar question was already asked [Find never-called functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4224758/find-never-called-functions)
but maybe someone have some other solutions?That don't require use of external programs.
I am working in c++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't a way of doing this built into Visual Studio. You will need a third-party program. Asking again isn't going to change anything. The duplicate question that you link to was asked and answered *well* after Visual Studio 2008 was available. Someone would have suggested something if it existed.

It's difficult to suggest any third-party solutions in *particular* because you don't specify a language in the question. What you would choose for an unmanaged C++ project would be different than a .NET project.

Comment: I use c++ I have edited the question

Comment: @Yakov: Then, I'm missing how the question you linked to fails to qualify as an *exact* duplicate.