# How to detect functions, that are only called from unused functions using cppcheck?

Tags: c++, static-analysis, cppcheck, dead-code

I'm trying to detect unused functions in C++. At the moment I'm trying to use cppcheck but i don't know if it is possible or how it is possible to detect functions, that are used but only by functions that are not used themselves.

Here's my little test code:

```
int bla() {
    return 0;
}

int test() {
    return bla();
}

int main() {
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;
    return b;
}
```

That's what cppcheck detects with my current settings:

```
$ cppcheck --enable=style,unusedFunction test.cpp 
Checking test.cpp...
[test.cpp:10]: (style) Variable 'a' is assigned a value that is never used.
Checking usage of global functions..
[test.cpp:5]: (style) The function 'test' is never used.
```

The problem is that it doesn't detect the function bla as unused, because its called in test. But test is never called so neither is bla. I want that all functions except for functions that are used by main are marked as unused.

Do you know a option for cppcheck?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find never-called functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4224758/find-never-called-functions)

Comment: I don't see any real issue here, you can iteratively find all the functions. Remove `test`, and run the check again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found my own solution using callcatcher http://www.skynet.ie/~caolan/Packages/callcatcher.html. It's not a static code analysis but it works exaclty how i want it to work.

Answer (score 2):

You can try [CppDepend](http://www.cppdepend.com) and its query language CQLinq, you can create with CQLinq advanced queries to filter the result as you want, for example in your case you can execute this query:

```
from m in Methods where m.MethodsCallingMe
.Where(a=>!a.SimpleName.Contains(("test"))).Count()>0
select m
```