# How to find functions that are almost overrides in c++

Tags: c++, inheritance

I hit a bug today where I'd inadvertently added a parameter to a virtual function thus breaking the virtual inheritance chain for any functions derived from it, e.g. starting with the code below

```
// Original code

class A
{
public:
  virtual int f() { return 0; }
}; 

class B : public A
{
public:
  int f() { return 1; }
}; 

int func1(A &a)
{
  return a.f();
}

int main
{
  B b;
  return func1(b);  // returns 1
}
```

an extra parameter is added to A::f() breaking the virtual inheritance for derived class B

```
// Modified code

class A
{
public:
  virtual int f(int x = 0) { return 0; }
}; 

class B : public A
{
public:
  int f() { return 1; }
}; 

int func1(A &a)
{
  return a.f();
}

int main
{
  B b;
  return func1(b);  // returns 0
}
```

This makes wonder in the large code base that I'm currently working with there could well be other similar bugs lurking undetected.  For new code, I use the [override](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/override) specifier, but for existing legacy code is there anyway of detecting this potential problem?  I'm using VS2015 Update 2.  As per this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4224758/find-never-called-functions), static code analysis will find code that is never called, but in this case it is still quite possible that the code is called from elsewhere.

Comment: Why not define macro `OVERRIDE` that depend on `c++03` or `c++11` compiler, so you can check your legacy code with new compiler, and still able to compile your `legacy` with old compilers?

Comment: The issue is not the C++ version so much as the huge refactoring effort that would be required going through every function in every class and adding override keywords as needed.

Comment: Then you need clang (+ optionally python) to check derived classes that have member functions with the same name as in base, but different signature.

Comment: There is *clang-tidy* which may add missing `override` to legacy code, to avoid future problems.

Answer (score 2):

The `override` feature in C++11 is exactly what you need here:

```
class B : public A
{
public:
  int f() override { return 1; } // will not compile
};
```

This feature was specifically design to catch cases like yours.

If you insist on checking this sort of thing without editing your code, then you can consider purchasing an advanced static analyzer.  Some of them can detect problems like this.  Clang can also detect it if you use `-Wall` (and you should!):

```
warning: 'B::f' hides overloaded virtual function [-Woverloaded-virtual]
    int f() { return 1; }
        ^
note: hidden overloaded virtual function 'A::f' declared here: different number of parameters (1 vs 0)
    virtual int f(int x = 0) { (void)x; return 0; }
```

Comment: To be precise, it's not a keyword. You can use it as variable or function name. It's *an identifier with a special meaning*.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: I have edited the answer to not call it a "keyword."  Pedants are dancing in the streets.

Comment: I was aware of the override identifier, just looking for a way of finding these potential errors without having to manually examine and edit a large body of code.  FWIW, a quick search shows 3255 occurrences of 'virtual' and many of the derive classes won't have the virtual specifier on the overriding function.  I'll try Clang.