# Is it possible to implement 'override'-like functionality in C++03

Tags: c++, polymorphism, overriding, virtual-functions, c++03

In `C++11` we have `override` specifier that allows to validate in compile time that virtual function actually overrides behavior of interface in the base class.

Is there anyway to get the same behavior in `C++03`?

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36954009/3233393)

Answer (score 3):

To check if a function `foo` exists in a base class `Foo` say, write

```
sizeof(&Foo::foo);
```

in the child class version of `foo`. The idea is that compilation will fail if the base class `Foo::foo` is not present, and has a benign effect if it is.

Of course, this has drawbacks - you can't descriminate by overloads for example. Also, `static` functions and member variables with a similar name will also match.

Comment: This will also match data members and static members though

Comment: Nice one. I didn't think about it. But still it is not 100% match.

Comment: @Quentin: Indeed it has its drawbacks: you point out another. You might be able to do something funky with templates, but I'd be concerned about code bloat in C++03.

Comment: @Bathsheba Well, with any optimization such a NOP will be eliminated, so (binary) code bloat should not be a concern. Oh, you are talking about the template idea. Yes, there it may be. The resulting instantiations may be eliminated together with the call but that's less clear or sure. And compile time will increase needlessly because of the ubiquitous template headers.

Comment: I think most issues with wrong override is extra/missing parameter (`void Base::f(int)` vs `void Derived::f(char)`) and not missing function...